# How to run Plutus code on Alonzo Purple without the PAB?

Tags: plutus, pab

I am trying to run my Plutus code on Alonzo Purple. However, the PAB currently isn't able to connect to the Alonzo Purple testnet.

Since the off-chain code lives in the Contract monad, do I need to somehow write code to 'interpret' the Contract monad and issue commands against the wallet and node?

Is there some example code to look at?

Answer (score 2):

For now, and until we have tools for it (the PAB for instance), you have to write your off-chain code as CLI transactions, which is obviously not ideal but the only solution at the moment.

I suggest going through the exercises of the [Alonzo-testnet](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet) to learn how to interact with Plutus scripts using `cardano-cli`.

The PAB is under heavy development but we don't have any release date for either the testnet or the mainnet.

Comment: What does 'write off-chain code as CLI transactions' mean? I understand that I'll have to call the cardano-node/cardano-cli/wallet to submit transactions and query the blockchain and what not. However, the off-chain code lives in the Contract monad. So, do you think I also need a layer to interpret the effects from the Contract free monad into the CLI? If so, is there any code examples I can take a look at?

Comment: No, there is no interpreter for now. What I mean by CLI transactions is, whatever off-chain code you have in your Contract monad you can re write it as a CLI transaction (because off-chain is nothing more than transactions). I suggest looking into the docs of `cardano-cli` and through the exercises of the [Alonzo-testnet](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet).

Comment: I looked at the Alonzo-testnet exercises but those pages are just an outline of exercises.  There was no detail and no step-by-step instructions.  Am I missing something?  I will be honest here - trying to learn this is becoming an exercise in frustration due to a lack of quality documentation.

Comment: Exercises are meant to have holes, if you want step-by-step check [Alonzo-solutions](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet/tree/main/Alonzo-solutions). The documentation **is** lacking but we have to accept it and keep digging it ourselves.